# How to count directed cycles in a directed graph according to the most standard terminology?

Tags: graph-theory

How many directed cycles are there?
[image]

Comment: Its not very clear to me which cycles should be regarded as the same. Definitions seem to vary.

Answer (score 1):

Every cycle includes node 1, so you might as well start and end there.  If you're not allowed to visit the same node more than once, there are three:
$$1\to 2\to 1\\ 1\to 3\to 1\\ 1\to 4\to 1$$

If you're allowed to visit the same node more than once but not traverse the same arc more than once, there are 5 more:
$$1\to 2\to 1\to 3\to 1\\
1\to 2\to 1\to 4\to 1\\
1\to 3\to 1\to 4\to 1\\
1\to 2\to 1\to 3\to 1\to 4\to 1\\
1\to 2\to 1\to 4\to 1\to 3\to 1
$$

If you're allowed to traverse the same arc more than once, there are an infinite number, corresponding to any word on alphabet $\{2,3,4\}$.

Comment: I think the most common definition considers that we can traverse a same arc only once but doesn't say anything about vertices. However are you sure that $1\to 2\to 1\to 4\to 1\to 3\to 1\\$ should be regarded as distinct from $1\to 3\to 1\to 2\to 1\to 4\to 1\\$ ?

Comment: Sorry for the overcounting. I corrected the answer just now.